# Dividing an image into N block in the width and calculating the edge points of each block Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Hello everyone I was trying to divide an image into N different blocks in the width after I performed this code to get its edge points:

```
Ioriginal = imread('sample.jpg') %read the image
Igray = rgb2gray(Ioriginal) %change it to gray scale
InoNoise = wiener2(Igray)  %remove noise from image
image = edge(InoNoise, 'prewitt') %get the edge points of the image
```

the result is shown in this picture:
[image]

Now what i want to do is dividing the image into N equal blocks in the **width** and calculate the edge points of each block

After the division, the image should be divided this way:
[image]

I really appreciate if someone can really help me doing this part

Thank you

Comment: Can you please upload the original image too?  I'd like to be able to reproduce your results.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by dividing an image into `N` equal blocks "in the width"?  Can you please elaborate?  I don't understand what this means.  Do you wish to keep the **height** of each block the same (probably the height of the image), and you want to decompose the image into blocks width-wise?  Can't you simply do an edge detection overall (which is what you've done), then split up the image into blocks for further analysis?  Why do you want to separate the image into blocks first, then calculate the edges?  If you're using the Prewitt operator, then it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @rayryeng I have updated the question, you may find the answer on how I want the image to be divided.

Comment: @rayryeng i wanted to divide it and then calculate the edge points in each block so that i use the results as input vectors in a Neural Network to use it for image recognition later on

Comment: Can we simply decompose the edge detected image into blocks?  Also, how would these blocks be stored?  In a 3D matrix? A cell array?  What is the output that is most compatible for your framework?

Comment: @rayryeng that's why i asked this question; because i don't know how to decompose it; but i'm sure that there is a way to do it since i'm trying to implement a method was used in this particular paper:
(RESEARCH ON PAPER CURRENCY RECOGNITION BY NEURAL
NETWORKS, ER-w ZHANG'", BO JIANG'JING-HONGD UAN',2003)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to decompose the edge detected image into `N` blocks where the height of each block is the height of the image, while the width of each block is computed such that it is of width `m`, where `N*m = width of image`.  Therefore, each block's width is `width of image / N`.  Bear in mind that you must choose a value of `N` such that it is evenly divisible by the width of your image.  Your image has 460 columns, and so we can choose any number of blocks that is divisible by 10 for example.... so let's choose something like 10 blocks.

The easiest way to decompose your image would be to use [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html).  This takes a 2D matrix and segments the matrix into pieces.  Each piece would be stored in an individual element in a cell array.  Therefore, you want to make sure that the height of each block is the same, and the width of each block is using that formula I gave you above.  Therefore, you simply need to do this.  I'm reading your example image that you posted directly from StackOverflow, but the image was actually uploaded as RGB.  I converted it to binary directly so that we get an actual edge map:

```
N = 10; %// Declare total number of blocks
im = im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvfoL.png')); %// Read in image
C = mat2cell(im, size(im,1), (size(im,2)/N)*ones(N,1));
```

`C` will contain your image blocks, where `C{idx}` will get you the image block located at index `idx`.  If you want to make this into a 3D array, where each **slice** gives you the image block you want, simply use [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) and concatenate in the third dimension like so:

```
C_matrix = cat(3, C{:});
```

Therefore, to access the block at `idx`, simply do `C_matrix(:,:,idx)`.

---

As a visual representation, let's display each block in a figure:

```
figure;
hold on;
for idx = 1 : N
    subplot(1,N,idx);
    imshow(C{idx}); %// Or imshow(C_matrix(:,:,idx));
end
```

---

This is what I get:

[image]

Basically, each block is placed in a separate figure within the window itself, which is why I'm using `subplot`.  You can see that there is a white gap in between the blocks, which properly shows you each separated block within your image.

---

Good luck!

Comment: Again, that's exactly what i wanted thank you very much

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi - You're very welcome.  Good luck with your recognition work!

Comment: @chappjc I know right!? I saw Amro do that in an earlier post. That blew me away!